# Safest and most efficient way retrieve and serve files/images from folder?

Tags: python, django

Say i have folder in the media directory called `/images/year/month/day`. I would like to get the image name and path for these images and have a page serve all the images in the directory.

I then have another folder called `/files` which contains application files. The same structure etc.

All uploads for files are recorded as part of a database. The images are not saved via a database hence i want to read all files from all sub directories under images possibly including the year month date information.

Is it safe to do such a thing and how would i go about doing so? What would i need to look for when doing so.

Thanks

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/) and then if it doesn't work, update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to do so, as long as you do proper escaping. You want to make sure you don't allow any directory traversal outside of that root-level media directory so that none of your application files get served.

You can do this with a simple barrier check:

```
dir_to_serve = os.path.abspath(dir_to_serve) # get full path
if not dir_to_serve.startswith(media_dir): # maybe settings.MEDIA_DIR here?
    return # don't ever serve this

# code to serve from path
```

In Django, you can simply pass a result list from [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.walk) to your template and loop through it. You may wish to filter out certain file types or directory names in your template that you don't wish to display.